# Генератор случайных чисел в C++

Tags: c++

Не подскажете как заполнить одномерный массив в установленном интервале, но не целыми числами, как это делает функция rand(), а десятичными?

Comment: Дясятичными - это имеется в виду с плавающей запятой?

Comment: Что вам мешает поделить целое на 10, 100, 1000? Или поделить единицу на целое число?

Comment: Да вот именно. Только на 10.0, 100.0 и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Для получения в интервале от 0 до 1

```
double r = rand()/RAND_MAX;
```

В интервале от l до m

```
((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*(m-l)+l;
```

Если требуется, чтобы при разных запусках была разная последовательность вызывайте srand(time(0)) перед генерацией последовательности.

Comment: В C++BUILDER еще имеется возможность работать со случайными нормально-распределенными числами.

Answer (score 1):

Более проприетарный и `production-ready` вариант - использование [**boost::random.**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random.html)

Answer (score 0):

Только rand() даёт всего 15 бит (от 0 до 32767), поэтому лучше использовать 2 rand'а:

```
unsigned int n=(rand()<<15)|rand(); //Целое число в интервале [0; 2^30)
double value=min+n/(double)(1<<30)*(max-min);  //Получаем число от min до max с достаточно высокой точностью
```

Comment: Доказать не смогу, но сильно сомневаюсь, что полученная таким образом последовательность будет отвечать критериям, предъявляемым к случайным числам. Навскидку, будет непропорционально много "больших" чисел.

Между прочим, в linux (может быть не во всех) rand() также как и random() дает 31 бит (на самом деле там это синонимы). 

В Windows random() отсутствует. Если на самом деле нужен хороший генератор, то видимо надо просто взять исходник из linux.

Comment: >Навскидку, будет непропорционально много "больших" чисел.

 Почему? rand недостаточно случаен?